# What's the difference between 一番星 and 最初の星?

Tags: word-choice, translation, meaning

What's the difference between [一番星]{いちばんぼし} and [最初]{さいしょ}の[星]{ほし} ?

Do they both mean *the first star* in the same context?

Answer (score 3):

Only 一番星 means *the first star*.  
If you call me up and say ''最初の星を見つけた'', I may not understand what you mention. I may wonder if you're looking in a new telescope, or you have researched the oldest star in the universe.